# Angular2 ng bootstrap datepicker minDate not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

ng bootstrap with minDate throws error "minDate value must be or return a formatted date"

**Component HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="date_of_birth" type="text" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" id="date_of_birth" formControlName="date_of_birth" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" (focus)="d.open()" [minDate]="minDate">
    <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component TS:**

```
minDate: NgbDateStruct = { year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1 };
```

Without minDate ng datepicker working fine. After assigning minDate it throws error

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bwg1gDnXR02G3COniV9f?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Comment: @JBNizet Works well without formControlName. After assigning  formControlName with form builder & group same issue.

Comment: Again, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Comment: @JBNizet working fine in plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/kq8Ok7Ixa2ofsfGgWhLg?p=preview but in angular CLI  same exception "minDate value must be or return a formatted date"

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with ng-bootstrap. You're probably using another directive whose selector is [minDate] or input[minDate]

Comment: @JBNizet you are right. ng2-validation module also having the same minDate directive. You Really Saved My Day. Thanks :-)

Comment: Someone (@JBNizet) should post that as the answer so it can be marked as correct and close out the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most probably a clash with the ng2-validation module if it exists on your application. This module also has the same minDate and maxDate directive, which can cause conflicts in your application. So you should check that.

You should remove the reference to the **`ng2-validation`** module in the module that is referencing the component having the error.

Comment: Exactly what I had